# Fancybox 1.3.4 — How to use multiple inline elements in a single gallery?

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, gallery

Usually you use [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/howto) in order to display a gallery consisting of multiple images where you can flip from one image to the next one (using arrows or the keyboard).

**Question:**
I would like to do the same with `inline` HTML elements, so that Fancybox opens the gallery, shows the first inline element, and if you click on the arrow, it would show the second inline element, etc.

How do you do that? Is it possible with Fancybox at all?

Here is my code **that works for a single HTML inline element**:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#inlinetest').fancybox({
        'type':'inline',
        'overlayShow': true,
        'overlayOpacity': 0.7,
        'overlayColor': '#666',
        'titleShow': false
    });
  });
</script>
<div>
  <a id="inlinetest"  href="#inlinedata">Click here</a>
  <div style="display:none;">
    <div id="inlinedata">
      <div>TEST</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the code **with TWO INLINE elements, that does not work**:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#inlinetest').fancybox({
        'type':'inline',
        'overlayShow': true,
        'overlayOpacity': 0.7,
        'overlayColor': '#666',
        'titleShow': false
    });
  });
</script>
<div>
  <a id="inlinetest"  href="#inlinedata">Click here</a>
  <div style="display:none;">
    <div id="inlinedata">
      <div>HTML Content of element 1 comes here</div>
    </div>
    <div id="inlinedata">
      <div>HTML Content of element 2 comes here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [displaying image/text gallery with Fancybox 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026458/displaying-image-text-gallery-with-fancybox-2)

Comment: The answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17028390/1055987 was for fancybox 2 but the `html` structure should be basically the same for v1.3.4 ... read the explanation in my answer, basically because you can't have several elements with the same ID (IDs should be unique) so you will need a different ID for each inline content.